# setVisibility(View.GONE) dose not work in ListView with CheckBox

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to develop a `ListView` with a `CheckBox`.
Text data is managed by SQLite, and `SimpleCursorAdapter` is used as an adapter.

When I click the `CheckBox`, I want to disappear it and narrow the space(not delete from the database). I use `setVisibility(View.GONE)` , but the space remains.

Why the space remain?
How should I implement it?

Listener:

```
 private class ItemClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        CheckBox selectedCB = view.findViewById(R.id.cb01);
        selectedCB.setChecked(!selectedCB.isChecked());
        selectedCB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/cb01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:text="" />
```

onCreate(MainActivity.java):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ADD);

        }
    });

    ListView lvCB = findViewById(R.id.lvCB);

    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from belongings",null);

    String[] from = {"name"};
    int[] to = {R.id.cb01};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.row,c,from,to,0);
    lvCB.setAdapter(adapter);

    ItemClickListener clickListener = new ItemClickListener();
    lvCB.setOnItemClickListener(clickListener);

    ItemLongListener longListener = new ItemLongListener();
    lvCB.setOnItemLongClickListener(longListener);
}
```

AddListener(AddActivity.java):

```
private class AddListener implements View.OnClickListener{

    Intent intent = new Intent();

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        EditText input = findViewById(R.id.editText_name);
        String inputStr = input.getText().toString();

        DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(AddActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO belongings (name) VALUES (?)";
        SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sqlInsert);
        stmt.bindString(1, inputStr);
        stmt.executeInsert();

        intent.putExtra("INPUT_STRING", inputStr);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to hide the entire row or just the checkbox? (From your current code, you're hiding only the checkbox and you have another issue there). If you want to hide the entire row, that's not the right way to do it

Comment: I want to hide the entire row. Do you mean I should use `view.setVisibility(View.GONE);` instead of `selectedCB.setVisibility(View.GONE);`?

Comment: @wakya You would have to remove the item from your adapter dataset

Comment: if you want to hide the entire row (but keep it in the database) then how do you want it reappear again?

Comment: @SapuSeven  I do not know what "adapter dataset" is. Does it refer to SQLite?

Comment: @pskink I will reappear it by refresh button or rebooting the application. When reappering, it redisplays everything. There is no action to reappear only one.

Comment: @wakya When you load the data from your SQLite database, you need to store it somewhere inside your adapter instance. Most of the times it is an ArrayList, called 'the _dataset_ of the adapter'.

Comment: @SapuSeven I understood. Thank you. However, I do not know how to access adapter dataset...

Comment: @wakya How do you instantiate the adapter and how do you add items to it?

Comment: @SapuSeven I added code on adapter instantiation and item addition. Please take a look. The application has two activity. One is activity for displaying ListView. Another is activity for adding items by input text and push save button.

Comment: @wakya Well, I am not familiar with `CursorAdapter`, but you have to somehow remove the item on click and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` (see @IulianPopescu's answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide an element of a list view, then you need to work with the adapter for that. In your case, using `setVisibility(View.GONE)` will hide the view, but you will see an empty space. Although you might be able to do some tricks to remove that space, doing an orientation change you will see that the list is in the initial state. The thing here is that your list will consider that item (since it is present in the adapter) and will display it. As a general rule of thumb, if you do something that affects a given view from a list view, you should always reflect that in some way in the adapter.

The correct way to hide something from a list view is to remove that item from the adapter and notify the list that something changed:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        // Write here the code to remove the item from the adapter

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // keep this unchanged
    }
});
```

Comment: I agree, but if you had any more code in the OnItemClickListener, this would get messy really fast...

Comment: Well, you shouldn't do too many things in there, so it's pretty safe.

Comment: @IulianPopescu I tried looking at SimpleCursorAdapter's reference, but I could not find a way to delete items from the adapter. How can I remove an item from the adapter?

Comment: Well, it depends on the adapter that you are using. If you have your own implementation, than you have to add a remove method. If you are using something like an ArrayAdapter, then you already have a remove method.